# How to get specific value out of ArrayList of type class with different values

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

This is a seperate file called students.java. I made another file called student.java with the class Student mentioned below, with the 3 attributes and it's constructor, setters and getters.

I made an ArrayList of type Student, student is a class with three attributes: name, nationality and grade average. I put three student objects in the ArrayList, and now I need to do maximum search and find the student with the highest grade average and output their name. How do I specifically choose only the gradeaverages of the  students in the arraylist.

```
public class Students {

private final ArrayList<Student> data;

public Students() {
    this.data = new ArrayList<>();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Student> data = new ArrayList<Student>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        String students_name = Console.readLine("What is the name of the student? ");
        String students_nationality = Console.readLine("What is the students nationality? ");
        double students_average = Console.readDouble("What is the students average? ");

        Student newStudent = new Student(students_name, students_nationality, students_average);

        data.add(newStudent);
        System.out.println(newStudent.toString());
    }
```

I did this to put the students in the ArrayList. When I put

```
double maximumGrade = newStudent.getGrade_average();
```

inside the loop, it works. But I want to do it outside of the loop. How do I assign the max grade average to the **first** student and then check if the other students have a higher grade average than the first one. This was relatively easy for me to do this in cpp. But I'm not very good at Java and Object Oriented Programming so I feel lost.

Afterwards I wanted to do a for loop (I'll write it in a way so you understand what I'm imagining bc idk how to do it exactly in java

```
double maximumGrade = newStudent.grade_average[0] (basically get the grade average of the first student)
for(int i = 1; i<3; i++)
{
  if(newStudent.grade_average[i] > maximumgrade)
{
   maximumGrade = newStudent.grade_average[i];
}
else
{
i++;
}
}
```

I didn't know how else to formulate the question. I am new to Java and the terms used there but I hope you get the point. Thank you!

Comment: Is `Console.readLine` `Java` or `C#`?

Comment: @Sedrick It is Java. It is from a file that my professor created that I included in my project. It allows me to read from the console. I know there are other ways to do so, but I used this way because it is easier.

Comment: When is the purpose of `Scanner in` considering you're using the custom `Console` class instead? --- What is the purpose of the `data` field? It is never used.

Comment: @Andreas I forgot to delete that line of Scanner in. data is used. If you look at it better, you can see I used data.add(newStudent)

Comment: That adds to the *local variable* named `data`. It certainly doesn't refer to the *instance field* named `data`, since the code is in a `static` method.

Comment: @LorisSecuro omg yes!!! Thank you so so much!! You made my day so much better by helping and I totally understand it now!! I rly appreciate it!